# Send SMS with Amazon SNS in node js : Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +XXXX is not valid to publish

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Here is my code for sending SMS to a particular number with AWS sms service.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: '{ID}',
            secretAccessKey: '{KEY}',
            region: 'us-east-2'
        });
        var sns = new AWS.SNS();

        var params = {
            Message: 'this is a test message',
            MessageStructure: 'text',
            PhoneNumber: '+XXXXXXXX'
        };

        sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });
```

But i got the following error in console

> 'InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +XXXXXX is
>   not valid to publish

Comment: Did you use real phone number or +XXXXXX? If real, can you show the format? I mean something like +123456789012

Comment: yes  i am using real phone number  here is the format `+91XXXXX` ,91 is the country code

Comment: You can test sending a message to the phone number by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Try this: `aws sns publish --phone-number +91XXXX --message "published"`

Comment: But i need apis

Comment: @Jabaa we understand that, but to restate the obvious, the point is that this is a troubleshooting step: you can use this **test** the number this way to determine whether the problem is (a) the number or (b) your code.  If the error is the same the problem is the number.  If the error is different, or no errors occur, the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 11):

Please try with setting the region to *"us-east-1"*. It worked for me before.

```
var sns = new AWS.SNS({ "region": "us-east-1" });
```

Answer (score 5):

It is a bit misleading to ask everyone to change the region to `us-east-1`.

All the supported region are listed in the following link:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html

P.S. I am new user, I can't add comments or edit anyone posts to include the supported list.

Answer (score 2):

SNS currently supports SMS only in the form of E.164 formats, please make sure you are using the same format.

Check it out here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Additionally, you are using SNS sms service in us-east-2, which does not support SMS delivery as of yet. Checkout the SMS enabled regions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html

Comment: Nop that's not true I can able to send messages to India numbers from my AWS sns console

Answer (score 1):

change your region **us-east-2** to **us-east-1** it worked for me

```
var sns = new aws.SNS({
    "accessKeyId": functions.config().aws.key,
    "secretAccessKey": functions.config().aws.secret,
    "region": "us-east-1",
});
```